# How did Skynet know about Kyle Reese?

Tags: plot-explanation, terminator-salvation, terminator-series

In *Terminator Salvation*, Skynet casts Kyle Reese and John Connor as its two most wanted humans. How did it know about Kyle Reese's existence? John Connor's story as something of a messiah appears to be well known. But is the fact that he was fathered by a time-travelling soldier from the resistance public knowledge? He is shown keeping his mother's tapes something of a secret.

(I haven't watched  *Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines*.)

Comment: As to your ammendment, as far as I know it wasn't adressed in *Terminator 3*.

Comment: I don't know of any proof, but it's plausible that Sarah Connor mentioned him at some point during her stay in the psych ward, which ended up in somebody's notes, then typed in a computer, then...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This exact question is covered on [SE SciFi & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26732/why-didnt-skynet-kill-kyle-reese) quite extensively, but I don't think it was ever resolved. There is a lot of speculation about this, but some just think that paradoxes ensue where time travel is used.

In another post on [SF&F](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22515/is-skynet-trying-to-turn-kyle-reese-into-a-terminator-at-the-end-of-terminator-4), they talk about an episode on T:TSCC where they show Kyle Reese being captured and at the Skynet facility. Here he is interrogated. They make mention of why he was there, primarily to force John Connor to attempt a rescue, but not to kill him.

There is plenty of speculation, but nothing hard and fast as to why or how Skynet knows about Kyle and why they are after him.

As for T3, it was the only showing (TV or movie) which did not feature Kyle Reese in some way (he was in out takes in T2), so it would not be of much help.

Comment: The *Kyle Reese* scene was one of the best scenes from *Terminator 2*, too bad they removed it from the cinema version (together with the "brain surgery" that made his *slight* humanization towards the end a bit more plausible). Just my two cents.